# Python parse all lines inside of a files and split them by folder structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, file, parsing

I have bunch of file inside of MyFolder, and I need somehow to split them like this:

MyFile.txt:

```
    C:/Storage/agent/temp/6620/sw/main/folder/Module/Types.h
    C:/Storage/agent/temp/6620/sw/main/folder/Module2/Types1.h
    C:/Storage/agent/temp/6620/sw/folder/folder/Module3/Type.h
    etc..
```

I need to split all lines to be in this format, since this folder after temp (6620) is changing, and also everything before 'sw' might change, so I would like to leave those as one part so I can do other stuff with others on "right" side, output should be:

```
BUILD_DIRECTORY(C:/Storage/agent/temp/6620)+sw(sw)+base_folder(main)+folder(folder)+module(Module)+file(Types.h)
```

Point is that sw will always be after BUILD_DIRECTORY, base folder always after sw, and module always BEFORE file.

my trying with no success, I manage to get BUILD_DIRECTORY and REST, but sw is always lost, I guess there is better way to do this:

```
for filename in files:
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        content = file.read().split('\n')
        for line in content:
            if not line: continue
            # Seperate full path to the module in variables
            BUILD_DIRECTORY, REST= line.split('/sw')
```

Hope my problem is clear enough.
Any suggestion is welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

so after some time I have managed to get what I need, not the best solution probably but it works:

```
for filename in files:
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        content = file.read().split('\n')
        for line in content:
            if not line: continue
            # Seperate full path to the module in variables
            BUILD_DIRECTORY, SW= line.split('sw/')
            sw+base_folder+folder+module+file = sw.split('\\')
```